# Get null by deserialize in C# from XML if string between tags

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xmlserializer

i need some help, i get allways null if i will deserialize a string between two xml tags.

The following example xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <item name='First Item' size='1'>
   <Bits value='0'>
     1st String
   </Bits>
   <Bits value='1'>
     2nd String
   </Bits>
 </item>
```

And i write the following classes:

```
[Serializable()]
public class Bits
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Bits")]
    public String entryString { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("value")]
    public int entryValue { get; set; }
}


[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("item")]
public class itemsReader
{
    public itemsReader()
    {
        _bitList = new List<Bits>();
    }
    [XmlElement("Bits")]
    public List<Bits> _bitList { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public String entryName { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("size")]
    public int entrySize { get; set; }
}
```

Only the entryString is always null!

To readout the XML file i use the following:

```
    itemsReader ireader = null;
    String path = @"PathtoString";

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(itemsReader));

    var reader = File.OpenText(path);
    ireader = (itemsReader)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have decorated `entryString` with `XmlElement` attribute which will search for an element `Bits` inside Bits itself.

But you want inner text of `Bits` element. For that we have another attribute called `XmlText`.

So change this

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "Bits")]
public String entryString { get; set; }
```

to

```
[XmlText]
public String entryString { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

i ran your code on your input and got the output, but the i saw, in the `Bits` class, that the property `entryString` has an attribute

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "Bits")]
```

but in your xml file there is no `<Bits>` tags around `1st String`. so i added them and got:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<item name="First Item" size="2">
  <Bits value="1">
    <Bits>firstOne</Bits>
  </Bits>
  <Bits value="2">
    <Bits>secOne</Bits>
  </Bits>
</item>
```

and then your code worked

so you can change the xml file or get rid of the attribute. your call